# Limit of nth roots of product of a sequence's terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that if $x_n$ goes to x, then $(x_1x_2\ldots x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ goes to $x$.

Comment: I've edited your question. Please take a look at it so that you could learn how to use LaTeX for next time.

Comment: Is it a limit? Do you mean to prove that when n goes to infinity?